# ACCESS SQL : How to retrieve all data of a table even though there no data joined with the other table

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a working SQL Statement for calculating wage and counting number for working days that one of SO's member here kindly help me solved it. However, the problem is that the result come out only labor that had worked on that period. What I really want is that the outcome must show all labors (in tbl_labor) no matter he had worked on that period or not.

```
select
  lab.lb_name,
  max(days),
  sum(prod.pdtn_qty * pdWk.pd_cost / 12) as Total 
from
  tbl_labor as lab,
  tbl_production as prod,
  tbl_pdWk_process as pdwk,

(select pdn2.lb_id, count(pdn2.lb_id) as days from
  (select  lb_id
  from tbl_production  pdn1
  where pdn1.pdtn_date >= #9/5/2012#
  and   pdn1.pdtn_date <= #2012-09-20#
  group by lb_id, pdtn_date ) as pdn2
     group by pdn2.lb_id) as pdn3

where prod.pdtn_date >= #9/5/2012#
and   prod.pdtn_date <= #2012-09-20#
and prod.lb_id = lab.lb_id
and   prod.pd_making_id = pdwk.pd_making_id
and lab.lb_id = pdn3.lb_id
group by lab.lb_name
```

Below is my related tables:

```
tbl_labor
 lb_id | lb_name  | lb_OT ($/day) | If_social_sec
   1   |  John    |    10         |    yes
   2   |  Mary    |    10         |    no
   3   |  Jane    |    10         |    no

tbl_production 
pdtn_date  | lb_id  | pdtn_qty(pcs) | pd_making_id 
 5/9/12    |   1    |     200       |    12
 5/9/12    |   1    |     40        |    13
 5/9/12    |   2    |     300       |    12
 7/9/12    |   1    |     48        |    13
 13/9/12   |   2    |     220       |    14
 15/9/12   |   1    |     20        |    12
 20/9/12   |   1    |     33        |    14
 21/9/12   |   2    |     55        |    14
 21/9/12   |   1    |     20        |    12

tbl_pdWk_process 
pd_making_id | pd_cost($/dozen) | pd_id 
    12       |     2            |   001
    13       |     5            |   001
    14       |     6            |   002
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Replace your old style joins

```
from
  tbl_labor as lab,
  tbl_production as prod,
...
where 
  lab.fld1 = prod.fld1
```

with newer LEFT JOIN

```
from
  tbl_labor as lab
  LEFT JOIN tbl_production as prod ON lab.fld1 = prod.fld1
...
```

Edit:
In your original code

```
from
  tbl_labor as lab,
  tbl_production as prod
...
where ...
prod.lb_id = lab.lb_id
...
```

creates a inner join between tbl_production and tbl_labor tables.
It needs to be replaced with newer style LEFT JOIN

```
from
  tbl_labor as lab
  LEFT JOIN tbl_production as prod ON lab.lb_id = prod.lb_id
...
```

You can read about SQL JOINs on http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_join.asp

Comment: Could you please elaborate this? With my limited skill of SQL I couldn't understand what do you meant especially "where 
  lab.fld1 = prod.fld1" What is this field that you pointed to? coz there're no such item in my statement.

Comment: Actually, I do understand about basic of LEFT JOIN. However with this SQL statement, I'm quite confused with your given answer. Because there are other conditions (Where pdn1.pdtn_date >= #9/5/2012... ) and other table (tbl_pdWk_process) that was crossed in the middle of statement that you left unmentioned. And I don't really know where to put it into. <br>Actually, I can create Count of Distinct Production date within given period. I can make it Sum wage amount. But I only can do it in separated sql. When put it together like this, It was beyond my skill.

Comment: Other conditions will remain as they don't relate to joins, they are basic selection criteria.  
In your code only `and prod.lb_id = lab.lb_id
and   prod.pd_making_id = pdwk.pd_making_id
and lab.lb_id = pdn3.lb_id` are join related. But you may need to add an extra condition to your where clause instead of the above that you will move to joins. The condition is `OR prod.pdtn_date IS NULL`. Try to work out why you may need it.

Comment: +1 This is being built in MS Access where the query design window should allow the OP to build suitable queries with point-and-click. For example, to add a join you can drag a field from one table to another, to change the join type, you can right-click the link and select from the options available. You can then view the SQL in SQL View of the Design Window.

Comment: @Remou Thank you for give me a direction. Actually, this always the way that I create simple SQL. However, when come to this complex statement, I seemed lost. But it's your reply that remind me how to change existing statement to what Germann advised me with this method :)